How do you set the default home page of a MAUI app?
Simple question that I don't seem to be able to find the answer to anywhere...
In a MAUI app, the first page navigated to when the app opens is the first one listed in the navigation.
How do I set it to be another page?
Googled and searched this site.
I have created a new project setting Route="MainPage" but the default page is still "Page 1"
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage1}" Title="Page 1" />
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage2}" Route="MainPage" Title="Page 2" />
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage3}" Title="Page 3" />
</TabBar>


What exactly have you tried? Are you using Shell? If you use Shell, just move the page you want to show up first all the way up in your AppShell.xaml. Alternatively, you can also navigate to another page using Shell.Current.GoToAsync() once AppShell was loaded.

I am using Shell. If I move the item up in AppShell.xaml then the tab for it will appear in a different sequence. I actually want the tab that appears second to be the default "home" page.

Where would I call Shell.Current.GoToAsync() from?

You should add this kind of useful information to the question and show the code you're currently dealing with and explain the problem in more detail.

Updated with code from a newly created project

In your AppShell.xaml change the MainPage property to any page you want to show first.
<ShellContent
    Title="Home”
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CustomPage}”
    Route="MainPage" />

Also can refer https://youtu.be/gzgbplKvci8?si=MiHMHCoRnIAsFXDg
You can change the first tab bar using CurrentItem="{x:Reference dogsItem}" where dogsItem is the name of the ShellContent for that page. Link to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs#tab-selection
For the issue where the tabs are hidden when Shell.CurrentItem is set (known MAUI bug), TabBar class the same tag so you can set CurrentItem in your TabBar declaration XAML instead of Shell.

My App.xaml.cs contains this at the moment MainPage = new AppShell(); .. how would I update this to point to another page please?

Just update the answer with correct location and also code snippet @spaced_uk

I tried adding Route="MainPage" to the ShellContent I want to display first but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Did you change the content template to point to your custom ContentPage.

I did yes. I've tried creating a new project adding 3 pages, referring them in appshell.xaml, giving the second one the property of Route="MainPage" but still no effect.  <TabBar><ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage1}" Title="Page 1" /><ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage2}" Route="MainPage" Title="Page 2" /><ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage3}" Title="Page 3" /></TabBar>

@spaced_uk You didn’t specify first that it was a TabBar. Updated the answer

Using CurrentItem="{x:Reference newPage2Name}" within appshell.xaml does show Page 2 on load, but it results in the tabs disappearing.

Refer to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11003 known issue @spaced_uk

Amazing! That did the trick! Adding CurrentItem="{Reference newPage2Name}" to TabBar rather than Shell did the trick. Thank you
